# Bluetooth keeps connecting and disconnecting

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, docker

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64) and the bluetooth keeps connecting and disconnecting. When I enter `bluetoothctl` and have devices paired etc. I try to connect to one of the devices by issuing `connect FC:8F:90:26:CF:47` it reports back saying connected and after 2 seconds it says disconnected.

I have got everything installed I think i.e.

- bluez is already the newest version (5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1)
- libudev-dev is already the newest version (237-3ubuntu10.23)
- libical-dev is already the newest version (3.0.1-5)
- libreadline-dev is already the newest version (7.0-3)

I know there was and update/upgrade of Ubuntu in early June 2019 which I did and ever since then I am having problems.

I just ran `journalctl -f` to check what happens when I try and access bluetooth from docker and this is the error I get:

```
nuc systemd[3274]: Failed to canonicalize path /home/bachoo786/.config/systemd/user/sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:15.0-usb1-1\x2d5-1\x2d5:1.0-bluetooth-hci0-hci0:3585.device.d: Permission denied
```

Furthermore I cannot use bluetooth in virtual environment either i.e. I am running docker containers that use bluetooth.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Do you have an internal Bluetooth adapter, or an external USB Bluetooth adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04 and managed to solve it with the below steps:

```
$ sudo apt install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils pavucontrol pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
$ killall pulseaudio
```

That's it! Try connecting again.